# What is the PnP tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the [[PnP](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pnp)] tag for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pen and paper. It is very redundant for this site, even if we wind up with some LARP questions. PnP is the default assumption, IMHO.

Comment: Agreed! That would _never_ have occurred to me.

Comment: Yeah, kill it.  Anything not PnP should not be here.

Comment: Agreed with all of the above.  I thought PnP was Plug-n-Play!